# Upgrade from Business Central On-Premise V14.23 to V15.17 On-Premise

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

I'm attempting to upgrade our Business Central On-Premise installation from Version 14 to 15, using the procedure on the link below.

[Installing a Business Central 2019 Release Wave 2 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/upgrade/upgrading-cumulative-update-v15)

I got to: 'Upgrade control add-ins' Step 1 (Open the Business Central client) This is the first time run after the upgrade. At this point we get: 'Something Went Wrong. An Error occurred.'

The Event Viewer reports:-

The metadata object Page 9006 was not found.

Message Fatal error during metadata load -- Type:Page; Id:0;MetadataGroup:0;MetadataLoaded:False; CLRLoaded:False; ThreadGroup:0

The metadata object Page 0 was not found.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you run `Get-NAVAppInfo -ServerInstance <server instance>` is the Base Application listed?

Comment: No. All extensions have been uninstalled as per the procedure.

Comment: Going from version 14 to 15 means that all code is moved to extensions. So if not extensions are installed, then you have no objects in your database.